Simplify a Powershell one-line function that works with pipelines as well as conventional parameters
I have the following PowerShell function that works as intended for pipeline and parameter usage:
function ext { 
  process {
    [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_ ? $_ : $args[0], $_ ? $args[0] : $args[1])
  }
}

Is it possible to simplify/minify this function by maybe using some Automatic Variables I don't know about, but without lengthening the code.
I explicitly don't want to go through all the parameter syntax like [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)] and defining each parameter explicitly since it would double the length of the function, which is exactly not my goal, unlike in these posts:

Make a Powershell function work correctly as both Pipeline and normal invocation
Handling pipeline and parameter input in a Powershell function


you can change function to filter and remove the process block if you want less code. Still is unclear what do you mean by using more automatic variables? you're already using 2 of them, what else is there that could be automatic ?

I mean whether there is some automatic variable I may not know about that works different depending on pipeline vs parameter input that convers my use case.

you're already covering both cases, pipeline $_, positional binding $args. There is no automatic variable that covers both in 1. you can use $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput ? $_ : $args[0] and same for the other condition but it only makes the code longer

Okay. Thanks for the information. The filter one is helpful as well. :)

The only possible simplifications to your current code are using a filter instead of a function with a process and removing System from System.IO.Path. There is no automatic variable that covers pipeline and positional binding both in 1.
filter ext { [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_ ? $_ : $args[0], $_ ? $args[0] : $args[1]) }

If you want to give your code more meaning or context you could use .ExpectingInput in your conditions however this makes it longer:
filter ext {
    [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(
        $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput ? $_ : $args[0],
        $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput ? $args[0] : $args[1])
}


No, you need to enable the function to receive pipeline input.
Which means [CmdletBinding()] and everything else.
